# prove that for any three sets A, B and C if (C-A)∪(B-C)⊆A-B , then B⊆A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

how we do you we prove that For any three sets $A, B, C$  If $(C-A)\cup(B-C)\subseteq A-B$ then $B\subseteq A$

My attempt: $x\in (C-A)\cup(B-C)$

$\rightarrow x\in(C-A)$ or $x\in(B-C)$

$\rightarrow x\in C\;$ and $\; x\notin A$ or $x\in B \;$and$\;x\notin C$ what next i cant go further

Comment: `If`$B\subseteq A$ or `then` $B\subseteq A$?

Comment: I would like to help but I think you may have written your question incorrectly.

Comment: "If statement 1 if statement 2".  That doesn't make sense.  ar you trying to prov statement 1 $\implies$ statement 2, or are you trying to prove statement 2 $\implies$ statement 1.

Comment: @sam..sorry i edited now

Comment: @fleablood.i was edited now

Comment: This means C - A $\subset A$.  This impossible unless $C \subset A$ and $C - A$ is empty.  So $B - C \subset of A-B \subset of A$.  But $B \cap C \subset A$ so $B \cap C \subset A$.  SO $B = (A-B) \cup (A \cap B) \subset A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in B$ and let's assume that $x \notin A$. We know that $x \notin A-B$

If $x \in C \implies x \in C-A \implies x \in (C-A) \cup (B-C) \implies x \in A-B $ which is a contradiction.

Can you take it from here? (You need to handle the case that $x \notin C$)

Comment: @benji..i am trying to understnd

Comment: @benji...what about if $x\notin C$

Comment: Sorry, I was about to clarify that this is the part that's remaining. Can you try that part on your own?

Comment: @benji...i am trying but working

Answer (score 0):

Given: $(C \setminus A)\cup (B \setminus C) \subset A \setminus B$.

$(C \setminus A) \subset (C \setminus A)\cup (B \setminus C) \subset A \setminus B \subset A$.

But $(C \setminus A) \cap A = \emptyset$  so $C \setminus A = \emptyset$.

So $C \subset A$.

$B \setminus C \subset (C \setminus A)\cup (B \setminus C) \subset A \setminus B \subset A$

$B \cap C \subset C \subset A$.

So $B = (B \setminus C) \cup (B \cap C) \subset A$.